# Mutate multiple columns

Tags: r

I am trying to calculated the difference between the first and the last value for the each Group for the each columne (Value1, Value2, Value3 etc).

```
Group    Dates      Value1 Value2 Value3
1      2000-01-01     NA      0      5
1      2000-02-01      1      0     10
1      2000-03-01      2      1      0
2      2000-04-01      4      1     NA
2      2000-05-01      1      2     NA
2      2000-06-01      2      2     40
```

For example: diff_Value1=-1 because the first value for the Group 1 is 1 and last value is 2.

I am using below code. How can I extend for 30 more columns (e.g. Value1...-Value 30)?
Do I need to use loop inside mutate function?

```
df <- data.frame(Group=c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3)),
                    Dates=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 6),
                    Value1=c(NA, 1:2,4,1:2),
                    Value2=c(0,0,1,1,2,2),
                    Value3=c(5,10,0,NA,NA,40)
)

df %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(
    Value1_diff = dplyr::first(na.omit(Value1))-dplyr::last(na.omit(Value1)),
    Value2_diff = dplyr::first(na.omit(Value2))-dplyr::last(na.omit(Value2)),
    Value3_diff = dplyr::first(na.omit(Value3))-dplyr::last(na.omit(Value3))
  )
```

```
 Group    Dates      Value1 Value2 Value3 Value1_diff Value2_diff Value3_diff
 1     2000-01-01     NA      0      5          -1          -1           5
 1     2000-02-01      1      0     10          -1          -1           5
 1     2000-03-01      2      1      0          -1          -1           5
 2     2000-04-01      4      1     NA           2          -1           0
 2     2000-05-01      1      2     NA           2          -1           0
 2     2000-06-01      2      2     40           2          -1           0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may use `across` to loop over multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('Value'),  
    ~ first(na.omit(.)) - last(na.omit(.)), .names = "{.col}_diff")) %>% 
    ungroup
```

-output

```
df
# A tibble: 6 × 8
  Group Dates      Value1 Value2 Value3 Value1_diff Value2_diff Value3_diff
  <dbl> <date>      <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1 2000-01-01     NA      0      5          -1          -1           5
2     1 2000-02-01      1      0     10          -1          -1           5
3     1 2000-03-01      2      1      0          -1          -1           5
4     2 2000-04-01      4      1     NA           2          -1           0
5     2 2000-05-01      1      2     NA           2          -1           0
6     2 2000-06-01      2      2     40           2          -1           0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately, I see that columns with all NAs may create error: do you have any suggestions here?




'df <- data.frame(Group=c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3)),
                 Dates=seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 6),
                 Value1=c(NA, 1:2,4,1:2),
                              Value4=c(rep(NA,6))
)



df <- df %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with('Value'),  
                ~ na_if(first(na.omit(.)) - last(na.omit(.)),NA), .names = "{.col}_diff")) %>% 
  ungroup`

Comment: @Lohengrin my code is not breaking with your new example.  But, you can also do `df %>%
   group_by(Group) %>%
    mutate(across(starts_with('Value'),  
    ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA_real_ else first(na.omit(.)) - last(na.omit(.)), .names = "{.col}_diff")) %>% 
    ungroup`